# Creating a Music bot from YT tutorial and running into a coroutine error. Thoughts on a fix?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This has been asked a couple times with no real answer, hoping to understand whats happening

Using a youtube tutorial I have followed this with plans to expand. In the video he does not get the error:

```
/home/runner/totallynotrithem/music.py:427: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
  bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl


class music(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.command()
  async def join(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("Aye, you have to be in a VC to use this!")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

  @commands.command()
  async def play(self, ctx, url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
      'before_options':
      '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
      'options': '-vn'
    }
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "best audio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, downlad=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)

  @commands.command()
  async def pause(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send("Paused. How rude.")

  @commands.command()
  async def resume(self, ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume()
    await ctx.send("Resumed. Damedane.")


def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

any help appreciated:)

I tried a few different tutorials and codeblocks from the internet to see if it was something I was doing wrong but the error persisted accross all of the ones I tried.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, [`add_cog`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_cog) is a coroutine and you need to treat it as such.

```py
async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(music(client))
```

And then when you call `setup` you gotta do `await setup(client)` as well. It is all [right here in the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html#cog-registration).